# Buildfire: plugin images not showing up in app in Testflight

Tags: buildfire

I'm working on a custom plugin for an app that we have deployed to Testflight. I am running into a problem where none of my plugin's images are displaying properly although I never ran into this problem with the web version of my app before I published to Testflight.

All of my images are in the `widget/.images` folder, and I am using relative paths to pull them in (e.g. `./.images/my-image.png`).

Additionally, I am using some icons that are included in Buildfire's Material icons that have also worked fine in the web app, but now do not show up in the Testflight app.

I am using the Material icons like this:

```
<i class="material-icons">edit</i>
```

And I am importing the Material icons css in my widget/index.html:

```
<link href="../../../styles/material-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Are the images pulled in any differently when the app has been published? Is there anything additional I need to add to my `widget/index.html` file?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it appears to be a bug on buildfire platform ignoring .images folder, can you change the folder for "images" instead of ".images". I believe that will fix your problem

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! But I am still having issues with the Material Icons not appearing (works fine in web app)

Comment: The icons are not loading due to an issue with Material Design. This should be fixed soon

Comment: We have deployed a fix for this issue

Answer (score 1):

that is the correct way of doing it. are you sure you have those images in the .zip file each time you upload? because in my experience previously uploaded files might still be served on web but on device only what get uploaded each time can be served.

Comment: Yes, I just double-checked and they are in my plugin.zip file when I upload the plugin.